# I am trying to create a rub gradient in css3 with opacity

Tags: css, gradient, opacity

I want to create a gradient that has opacity with css3 so that the child elements that are placed in a div don't inherit the opacity, and the background can be a gradient. Here is the code I am attempting to use but it simply doesn't work. it just shows up as white.

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgb(189,206,226,0.6) 0%, rgb(191,217,242,0.6) 32%, rgb(14,94,95,0.6) 65%);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set color's opacity you must use `rgba` instead of `rgb`.

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgba(189,206,226,0.6) 0%, rgba(191,217,242,0.6) 32%, rgba(14,94,95,0.6) 65%);
```